# How do i "put a restriction" on a list of permutations and subsequences of a list?

Tags: haskell

I'm really new to programming and Haskell in particular (so new that I actually don't know if this is a stupid question or not). But I was watching the lecture given by Eric Meijer (http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Erik-Meijer-Functional-Programming-Fundamentals) and i was fascinated by the program written by Dr. Graham Hutton in lecture 11; The countdown problem.

My question is:
Is there a way of "filtering" the list of solutions by the length (number of elements), so that the list of solutions are restricted to the solutions that only uses (for example) three of the source numbers? In other words, I would like to change the question from "given the numbers `[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9]` construct `18` using the operators..." to "given the numbers `[..]` which three numbers can be used to construct..."

In my futile attempts, I've been trying to put a kind restriction on his function `subbags` (which returns all permutations and subsequences of a list)

```
subbags :: [a] -> [[a]]
subbags xs = [zs | ys <- subs xs, zs <- perms ys]
```

So that I get all the permutations and subsequences that only contain three of the source numbers. Is this possible? If so, how?

Like I said, I have no idea if this is even a legitimate question - but I have gone from curious to obsessed, so any form of help or hint would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: J. Abrahamson's answer is fine, but it is important to remember that  as a general strategy, it represents a search on a possibly enormous space.  It may be better to enumerate the admissible elements than to enumerate all the elements and filter on properties.

Comment: I was working my way up to that :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to just select from the candidates three times

```
[ (x, y, z) | x <- xs, y <- xs, z <- xs ]
```

although this assumes that repeat use of a single number is OK.

---

If it's not, we'll have to get smarter. In a simpler scenario we'd like to pick just two candidates:

```
[ (x, y) | x <- xs, y <- ys, aboveDiagonal (x, y) ]
```

in other words, if we think of this as a cartesian product turning a list into a grid of possibilities, we'd like to only consider the values "above the diagonal", where repeats don't happen. We can express this by zipping the coordinates along with the values

```
[ (x, y) | (i, x) <- zip [1..] xs
         , (j, y) <- zip [1..] xs
         , i < j
         ]
```

which can be extended back out to the `n=3` scenario

```
[ (x, y, z) | (i, x) <- zip [1..] xs
            , (j, y) <- zip [1..] xs
            , (k, z) <- zip [1..] xs
            , i < j
            , j < k
            ]
```

---

Ultimately, however, this method is inefficient since it still has to scan through all of the possible pairs and then prune the repeats. We can be a bit smarter by only enumerating the above diagonal values to begin with. Returning to `n=2` we'll write this as

```
choose2 :: [a] -> [(a, a)]
choose2 []     = []
choose2 (a:as) = map (a,) as ++ choose2 as
```

In other words, we pick first all of the pairs where the head of the list comes first and a value in the tail of the list comes second—this captures one edge of the upper triangle—and then we recurse by adding all of the upper diagonal values of the list of candidates sans the head.

This method can be straightforwardly extended to the `n=3` case by using the `n=2` case as a building block

```
choose3 :: [a] -> [(a, a, a)]
choose3 [] = []
choose3 (a:as) = map (\(y, z) -> (a, y, z)) (choose2 as) ++ choose3 as
```

which also provides a direct generalization to the fully general `n` dimensional solution

```
choose :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
choose 0 as = [[]]            -- there's one way to choose 0 elements
choose _ [] = []              -- there are 0 ways to choose (n>0) elements of none
choose 1 as = map (:[]) as    -- there are n ways to choose 1 element of n
choose n (a:as) = map (a:) (choose (n-1) as) ++ choose n as
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this solution, which does not require the list elements to be an instance of `Eq`:

```
import Data.List (tails)

triples ls = [[x,y,z] | (x:xs) <- tails ls, 
                        (y:ys) <- tails xs, 
                         z     <- ys]
```

This returns only subsequences, not permutations, though.